# How can I display the current value of an integer on the screen of my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an integer y in my AppDelegate.mm file that I want to display on the screen of my iphone app (xib file).  The y value ranges from a value of 0 to 1024 and is constantly changing because it is reflective of the frequency going into the mic port of the phone.  Is there an easy way just to display the current value of y on the app screen like a monitor? Thank you so much for your time,
Timothy Lowry

Comment: Add a UILabel to your UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  NSTimer.

The timer use periodically call the method and your updated value will be reflected/changed in the uilabel.

EDIT: As suggested by h2co3

If the app uses audio data, it's almost sure it has a callback function designated for that - one should really use that callback instead of a timer.

Comment: Reasonable solution (+1), however you could add that if the app uses audio data, it's almost sure it has a callback function designated for that - one should really use that callback instead of a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a UILabel and add it to your view with a integer casted to an NSString.
You will need a view controller to do this though.

```
       int yourInt;
       NSString *num = [NSString strinWithFormat:@"%d", youInt];
       UILabel *lab = [UILabel alloc] initWhithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 30)];
       lab.text = num;
       [self.view addSubView:lab];
```

Code is untested, I just wrote this straight into the solution box.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display value of Appdelegate integer y in xib

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
lbl.text = [NSString strinWithFormat:@"%d",appDelegate.y];
```

Make sure your y integer is set to property in AppDelegate

Hope this helps you..