# how to display int in UI Label?

Tags: ios

I need to display an int in AppDelegate.mm in a UILabel.  I'm a newb so I'm not sure how to do this.  Xcode, 4.3.  Right now, I have a UILabel in the xib file and an integer y in the AppDelegate.mm.  I just need to have y be displayed in the UILabel.  I don't know how to connect these two things.  Thanks, Tom Lowry.

Comment: Was this a question from earlier?  Can you show some of your code so we know what you're working with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541249/how-can-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-integer-on-the-screen-of-my-app/14541285#14541285

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over...

Comment: There was a question like this earlier today   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541249/how-can-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-integer-on-the-screen-of-my-app/14541285#14541285

Comment: @AgnosticDev, I voted to close and flagged it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

Try this Function to display an Int in a Label:

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 3];
```

Comment: Hey Joel, where do I put that bit of code up there^? In the delegate?  Thanks, Tom

Comment: You are going to have to create a connection from your .xib into your source code. If you are struggling with this I would recommend looking up some good, basic, starting tutorials on youtube or somewhere else. I started out with the free Standford lectures on iTunesU, which I found most helpful! They have a whole class on there (mobile dev focus) and I am sure it would really help you out!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.Yourlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Y];
```

**Variable Y is int Value that declare...**

Answer (score 0):

```
       int yourInt;
       NSString *num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", youInt];
       UILabel *lab = [UILabel alloc] initWhithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 30)];
       lab.text = num;
       [self.view addSubView:lab];
```